# Java - Netbeans saving .txt files outside of project in server config folder

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8, filewriter, printwriter

I've been developing an application in Netbeans, and I am trying to write to a .txt file called "users.txt". See the below code.

```
File file = new File("users.txt");
    try{
        //create file if need be
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        //writers.
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file, true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);

        //user data to the file
        pw.println(userID + "." + userPassword + "." + userFirstName + "." + userSurname);
        pw.flush();

        //Closes the file stream
        pw.close();
    }
```

My issue is, however, whenever I run the program, it saves the file in my GlassFish server, in the 'config' folder, and not the local files, which is what I need it to do. I've gone into the project properties, and changed the working directory to the folder the project is in, but it doesn't change it.

Am I missing something completely obvious, is there a setting I need to change within NetBeans itself, or something I haven't even thought of?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Just pass the absolute path to the directory where you would like it to reside when you instantiate the File object, for example: `File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Foo\\Desktop\\users.txt");`

Comment: I have tried absolute paths, and they work, however I did want to use relative paths, as using relative paths would stop the program from working on any PC other than my own.

Comment: You can use a System call to get the path on the machine your program is running on, for example `File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\Desktop\\users.txt");`

Comment: And for completeness sake, just in case you changed it in the wrong spot - to change your workdir in NetBeans, right click 'Source Packages' for your project in the Projects window, select 'Properties' then click on 'Run' in the left Categories column, and change the path in the 'Working Directory:" field.